# zeppelin not showing hive tables in CDH cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

i am running zeppelin referring to CDH cluster. sql paragraph doesnot work. sample example showing bank file to be loaded and registered as temp table works.. but not the hive metastore tables.

How to make the default references to hive metastore?

---

```
%spark

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("use database_name")

val df = sqlContext.sql("select * from table_name")

df.registerTempTable("table_name")
```

---

```
%sql
show tables
select * from table_name
```

---